# Running on a real device (iPhone) linker error for an archive file

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm using [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) in my project by adding the project file directly in the project. When I compile it for simulator it is fine, but when I try to compile it for the real device it says:

```
"clang: error: no such file or directory: 
'/Users/t2wu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HRM-fqohcvzyvosuqmerfynaixyulpta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a'"
```

What could be the problem? I'm using iPhone 4S with iOS 6 SDK with architecture set to Standard(armv7, armv7s) for both the super project and the embedded CorePlot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Target Project Build Setting Make Buidl Architecture Only = YES. This will solve your problem.

Comment: This works but why is this necessary? In another project which also uses other sub project I load it on the device just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Clang is the compiler. Make sure you have a libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a file in your project.